# How to change value in one cell to value in another (pandas)

Tags: python

I am trying to create some lag features by subtracting a month from each date in my datetime column and then assigning a column value from the past date to the current one.

This is my code:

```
for row_index in range(0,len(merger)):
    date = merger.loc[merger.index[row_index],'datetime']
    prev = subtract_one_month(date)
    inde = merger.loc[merger['datetime'] == str(prev),'count'].index.values.astype(int)
    if inde == []:
        continue
    else:
        inde = inde[0]
    merger.loc[merger.index[row_index], 'count_lag_month'] = 
    merger.loc[merger.index[inde], 'count']
```

The inner if else loop is meant to deal with cases where the date I'm looking for doesn't exist.

The code above simply gives me a list of NaNs. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my

```
first = []
mean = []
wrkday = []
count = []

for row_index in range(0,len(merger)):
    print(row_index)
    date = merger.loc[merger.index[row_index],'datetime']  
    prev = subtract_one_month(date)
    inde = merger.loc[merger['datetime'] == str(prev)].index.values.astype(int)
    if inde.size == 0:
        first.append(0)
        mean.append(0)
        wrkday.append(0)
        continue
    else:
        inde = inde[0]
        first.append(merger.loc[merger.index[inde], 'count'])
        mean.append(merger.loc[merger.index[inde], 'monthly_mean_count'])
        wrkday.append(merger.loc[merger.index[inde], 'monthly_wrkday_mean_count'])
    prev_day = subtract_one_day(date)
    inde = merger.loc[merger['datetime'] == str(prev_day)].index.values.astype(int)
    if inde.size == 0:
        count.append(0)
        continue
    else:
        inde = inde[0]
        count.append(merger.loc[merger.index[inde], 'count'])      

merger['count_lag_month'] = first
merger['monthly_mean_count_lag_month'] = mean
merger['monthly_wrkday_mean_count_lag_month'] = wrkday
merger['count_lag_day'] = count
```

It uses lists instead and it seems to run at a decent speed. I'm not sure if it's the best approach though.